# Easy solution to a complex task

Tags: regex, bash

I am curious if there's an easy solution for this seemingly complex task:

Say I have this file:

```
lineone
linetwo
linethree
linefour

lineone
linetwo
linethree
linefour

lineone
lineone
lineone
linetwo
linethree
linefour
```

Is there a simple way you can think of to get this result:

```
lineone[1]
linetwo[1]
linethree[1]
linefour[1]

lineone[2]
linetwo[2]
linethree[2]
linefour[2]

lineone[3]
lineone[4]
lineone[5]
linetwo[3]
linethree[3]
linefour[3]
```

To put it in words, is there a simple bash algorithm that would let me number each line in the order of it's occurence in a file? I cannot figure out a way to do this without some complex solution involving additional storage, and the usual commands I use for line replacement are useless here. sed would just replace all occuring lines with the same value, and the string replace ( ${string/substring/replace} ) would not help me since it will not maintain the order of the lines.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, the numbers are only based on the content of the line, not which block of text the lines are in, right?  So if you have `lineone\nlineone\nlineone` you would get `lineone[1]\nlineone[2]\nlineone[3]`?

Comment: Questions like this are often easier for us to answer if you supply real data, because this could be an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @F.J, yes your first statement is correct, the numbers are only based on the content of the line. I do apologize for any confusion, I am relatively new to bash.

Comment: You should edit your example data so that you have multiple lines in the same block with the same content, that way it will be more clear to potential answerers what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `awk` command works by keeping an array of lines and their counts.

```
awk '{if($0~/./){a[$0]++;print $0"["a[$0]"]";} else print}' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
lineone
linetwo
linethree
linefour

lineone
linetwo
linethree
linefour

lineone
linetwo
linethree
linefour

lineone
lineone
lineone
linetwo
linethree
linetwo

$ awk '{if($0~/./){a[$0]++;print $0"["a[$0]"]";} else print}' file
lineone[1]
linetwo[1]
linethree[1]
linefour[1]

lineone[2]
linetwo[2]
linethree[2]
linefour[2]

lineone[3]
linetwo[3]
linethree[3]
linefour[3]

lineone[4]
lineone[5]
lineone[6]
linetwo[4]
linethree[4]
linetwo[5]
```

Comment: This will also match any lines that only contain one or more spaces. I've changed the awk expressions to match lines that are not comprised entirely of spaces: `awk '{if($0'\!'~/^[ ]*$/){a[$0]++;print $0"["a[$0]"]";} else print}'` The quotes around `\!` are because of some strange escaping issue with the `!` character.

Answer (score 2):

A quick 100% pure bash answer:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A lines=()
while read -r l; do
    if [[ -n "$l" ]]; then
        echo "$l[$((++lines[$l]))]"
    else
        echo "$l"
    fi
done < file.txt
```

This is, as required, a *simple bash algorithm that would let [you] number each [non-empty] line in the order of it's occurence in a file*.

It's not the fastest way (the `awk` answer is faster and more efficient but the `awk` answer is not a *bash algorithm*).

The trick is to use an associative array `lines`, the keys of which are the lines of the file, and to increment the value of the corresponding key each time a non-empty line is read.

Or a one-liner so as to impress your grand-mother:

```
declare -A lines=(); while read -r l; do [[ -n "$l" ]] && echo "$l[$((++lines[$l]))]"; || echo "$l"; done < file.txt
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the array. Use a simple counter instead, initialized to 1, and increment it when you see the empty line.

Comment: @chepner: It's not a counter that should be incremented each time an empty line is seen. Instead it's _number each line in the order of it's occurrence in the file_. See dogbane's example's output.

Answer (score 2):

A cryptic-ish Perl one-liner:

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/$/"[". $. . "]"/gem'
```

---

I see I misunderstood the question based on the ambiguous example. Here's the Perl snippet to number the lines as described:

```
perl -lpe '/\S/ and $_ .= "[" . ++$n{$_} . "]"'
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because I misunderstood the question, but then realized that it is not correct: it only counts paragraphs, not the number of times a line is repeated.